# Android development on eclipse: activity 1 changes to activity 2 fine, not 3

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Sorry for my bad English, I speak French.
I am trying to make a simple app with 4 activities.
In the first one (MainActivity), if I click on the "rechercher" button, it switches to the second activity (RechercherActivity). Then I can go back to MainActivity.

In MainActivity, I can click on 3 buttons ("rechercher", "trouvez" and "liste").
The first one works fine, but not the other two, even though I have created them in the same way. "RechercherActivity" was the first of those 3 which I have made.

When I click on "trouvez" or "liste", I get "the application stopped working" error message, and this is what shows up on LogCat: Problems start at the second line.

[image]

```
    package com.example.jouons;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupTrouvezButton();
        setupRechercherButton();
        setupListeButton();
    }

    private void setupListeButton() {
        Button listeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMainListe);

        listeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListeActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupTrouvezButton() {
        Button trouvezButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMainTrouvez);

        trouvezButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TrouvezActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupRechercherButton() {
        Button rechercherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMainRechercher);

        rechercherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RechercherActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and

```
    package com.example.jouons;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class RechercherActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rechercher);

        setupRetourButton();
    }

    private void setupRetourButton() {
        Button retourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRechercherRetour);

        retourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RechercherActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rechercher, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and

```
 package com.example.jouons;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TrouvezActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trouvez);

        setupRetourButton();
    }

    private void setupRetourButton() {
        Button retourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRechercherRetour);

        retourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(TrouvezActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.trouvez, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and

```
    package com.example.jouons;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ListeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste);

        setupRetourButton();
    }

    private void setupRetourButton() {
        Button retourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRechercherRetour);

        retourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ListeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.liste, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jouons"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RechercherActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rechercher" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TrouvezActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_trouvez" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_liste" >     
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks!

Comment: i hope you are using same button for last two activity, so check the button id in xml and do it correctly. Both listactivity and Trouvez having same button id         Button retourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRechercherRetour);

Comment: @Trexiic:How about u change the startActivity() on button click to YourActivityName.Finish()

Comment: Madhu: Thanks! It worked, I used copy/paste too much and forgot to change that. R.id.btnRechercherRetour is for the RechercherActivity, ListeActivity should use R.id.btnListeRetour, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You should override the onClick method inside OnClickListener.

```
private void setupListeButton() {
        Button listeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMainListe);

        listeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override         // this is what you are forgetting
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListeActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use different id for different buttons. If you are developing with eclipse then you are supposed to get compile time error for buttons you have used same id.